# Getting list of Facebook page status' updates in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

How can I pull a list of all of a Facebook page's status updates in Android? This seems like such a simple question, but seems to be a very difficult task. I don't want to have to use the SDK. I thought it would be simple like twitter... http request and parse the resulting json. From research, the only way I seem to be able to get JSON out of Facebook is with their Open Graph, which requires registering an application, and generating access tokens. This seems like overkill just to try and get public status updates. Is there something I'm missing?

Im not trying to make any status updates, or get any other information. Im only wanting to read the public statuses off of a single Facebook page.

Comment: Did you fix your problem???.If you did this feature please provides guidelines to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Use Url like this

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" +facebook_User_name +"/statuses&limit=20&access_token=" + access_token
```

you have to pass that url to HttpGet method for getting information.

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);    
HttpResponse response;  
try {
   response = httpclient.execute(httpget);          
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();             
   if (entity != null) {    
       InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
       result= convertStreamToString(instream);
       JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);             
           JSONArray valArray = json.getJSONArray("data");

       for(int i=0;i<valArray.length();i++) {             

           String info = main_object.getString("message");
       }
       instream.close();
    }            
} 
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {             
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So through Open Graph with an access token is the only way? I wish it could be as easy as twitter. If I'm not mistaken, the access tokens expire do they not? How to I generate them?

Comment: If you want to use facebook in your app you have to get accetoken, that should be required for any requirement in facebook. just use facebook graph api for getting accetoken and then use that in my code and you will status informations....you can get facebook sample application for here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk little bit difficult than Twitter, i worked on both Facebook and twitter status message read..

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy I am using your answer for getting facebook page post information but i got the following error message {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Unknown path components: \/statuses&limit=20&access_token=CAACbPB321y0BALdJGYwRbtYUEOac0jq2J1IAd40XFYvMQ8vOVZAEJ9xggaAVnNAAfq9f1PVh0eEG9o4JCszdSJdl8bLPhonmvUnQWGFxdg89Pfjhq4Q9sOMwMxZBmMDiGp9NBW0NSSHkzqSURyCltmBXkAFuhBY3YkzLWxO9FAiWVfWLCk","code":2500}}

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy Please give me the solution for my issues\

Comment: Check latest Facebook sdk for this, i had answered earlier with old sdk. now it's changed.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy can you give the sample coding for latest Facebook sdk

Comment: @Yes i achieved by using this url https://graph.facebook.com/"your page name"/feed?access_token="your access token"

Answer (score 0):

Please use this url to get the list of posts from facebook page

```
https://graph.facebook.com/"YOUR PAGE NAME"/feed?access_token="YOUR ACCESS TOKEN"
```

If you want to get your own facebook posts details use the beleow url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token="YOUR ACCESS TOKEN"
```